# does linux sort have incompatible arguments

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

I wanted to sort a file in numerical order as well as uniquify with the `sort -nu [filename]`.

```
$ *** | sort -n  | wc
201172
$ *** | sort -nu | wc
9599
$ *** | sort -un | wc
9599
$ *** | sort -n  | sort -u | wc
201149
$ *** | sort -u  | wc
201149
```

Why there is a decrease in number of lines with `sort -un` ? So I tried running above commands on a small numeric file and see if there is any problem. It worked as expected.

- Am I missing something obvious ? or
- those options incompatible with each other ? I've checked `man sort` for this, no information was provided about this combination.
  Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

- How should I fix this ? (using the `n` and `u` options separately ?)

Comment: no fix, the command you gave is fine already. What output do you need? read the man again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-u` removes duplicates.

So yeah, obviously it will reduce lines if the key is repeated within the file.

The difference with

```
sort -n | sort -u
```

then is that the second `sort -u` pipe command considers the full line, not just the numeric key.

Answer (score 0):

so you need understand what's the meaning of -u and -n.

```
man sort

 -u              Unique: suppresses all but one in  each  set
                 of lines having equal keys. If used with the
                 -c option, checks that there  are  no  lines
                 with  duplicate keys in addition to checking
                 that the input file is sorted.


 -n    Restricts the sort key to an initial  numeric  string,
       consisting  of  optional  blank  characters,  optional
       minus sign, and zero or more digits with  an  optional
       radix  character  and thousands separators (as defined
       in the current locale), which is sorted by  arithmetic
       value.   An  empty  digit  string  is treated as zero.
       Leading zeros and signs on zeros do not affect  order-
       ing.
```

Comment: What did you explain? This reads as "RTFM". As such it should be a comment.